Lenz Law for a Copper Tube instead of loops
Lenz Law tells us
$$\epsilon=-N\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$
Where N is the number of loops, and they conduct a current to oppose the change in flux.
I'm wondering what this would look like for a tube instead; I assume there would be some constant involving the material's conductivity, along with thickness in the equation, but couldn't find much online. Is there some equation that can relate $N$ to some kind of summation of tiny currents in the tube?
